# $f\leq g\text{ a.s}~\Longleftrightarrow f^+\leq g^+\text{ a.s.}$ and $f^-\leq g^-\text{ a.s.}$?

Tags: measure-theory, functions

> > If I have measurable functions $f,g$ that do not have to be non-negative, then I can split them in two non-negative measurable functions, i.e.
> >     $$
> > f=f^+-f^-,~~~~~g=g^+-g^-.
> > $$
> >     I have two questions to this, maybe silly ones, but I would like to prove that:
> >     $$
> > (1)~~~~~f=g\Longleftrightarrow f^+=g^+\wedge f^-=g^-?
> > $$
> >     $$
> > (2)~~~~~f\leq g\text{ a.s.}\Longleftrightarrow f^+\leq g^+\text{ a.s.}\wedge f^-\leq g^-\text{ a.s.}?
> > $$

I do not know exactly how to prove that.

**(1)** 
$$
f=g\Longleftrightarrow f^+-f^-=g^+-g^-\Longleftrightarrow f^++g^-=g^++f^-\Longleftrightarrow ?
$$

**(2)**
$$
f\leq g\text{ a.s.}\Longleftrightarrow f^+-f^-\leq g^+-g^-\text{ a.s.}\Longleftrightarrow ?
$$

Comment: In (2), use $f^-\geqslant g^-$, not $f^-\leqslant g^-$.

Comment: Ok, but why is: $f\leq g\text{ a.s.}\Longleftrightarrow f^+\leq g\text{ a.s.}\wedge f^-\geq g^-\text{ a.s.}$? I do not see that.

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: Ok, I thin I understood it